# what does @url do?

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

I came upon this `@url` in ajax request calling part.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "{{ @url("/accounts/upload-sf/validate") }}",
       data: formData,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function(response_json) { ...
```

Is `@url` any different from `url`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Laravel directives. You can create custom functions to use in blade templates. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-blade

See method signature:

```
if (! function_exists('url')) {
/**
 * Generate a url for the application.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  mixed   $parameters
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator|string
 */
function url($path = null, $parameters = [], $secure = null)
{
    if (is_null($path)) {
        return app(UrlGenerator::class);
    }

    return app(UrlGenerator::class)->to($path, $parameters, $secure);
}
```

}

Comment: I think this answer lacks the primary difference that `url()` is used in PHP environments (like within curly braces: `{{ url('something') }}`) and `@url()` is used in blade templates **outside** of PHP environments for convenience.